# after fill the form, i unckeck the checkbox, form is not showiing but data are still getting why?

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form

please, help me, when i check the checkbox then  i fill the form and submit, after then i got data in console. but if after fill the form, i unckeck the checkbox, form is not showing as condition but when i click the submit button i get same data. what should i do so that data show undefined or null after submitting when checkbox is unckecked. you can see on codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-modal-form-conditional-inputs-c7n0r?file=/src/App.tsx:1925-1955

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please could you edit your question and use the snippet button to put the code into the question otherwise you question is off topic for SO and will most likely be closed - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.